# Erro no upload de imagem: Undefined index

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao tentar fazer o upload de uma imagem por PHP.

Campo no formulário:

```
<input type="file" name="imagem" id="ff_imagem_serv"/>
```

Aí quando dou *submit* ele executa o código:

```
$name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

$location = "imagens_noticia/$name";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Não funciona. Da erro nas duas primeiras linhas $name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Erro:  Undefined index: imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve verificar se `$_FILES['imagem']` existe com a função [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php).

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagem'])){
    $name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
    $location = "imagens_noticia/$name";

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
}
```

Não esqueça de usar o atributo [enctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) com o valor `multipart/form-data` quando for realizar o envio de arquivos, ele é usado para especificar como os dados do formulário devem ser codificados quando enviados para o servidor.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

w3Schools - [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp):

> Os caracteres não são codificados. Este valor é necessário quando você estiver usando formulários que têm um controle de upload de arquivos.

Comment: Salvou minha vida! Muito obrigado!